# What is the best method to hunt Cactuar?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I'm looking to hunt cactuar for the Oracle-Ascension Coins / Experience, but it seems that there spawn conditions are fairly specific. Does anybody know the best method to consistently farm them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Game Skinny](http://www.gameskinny.com/j16gi/final-fantasy-xv-guide-how-and-where-to-find-the-elusive-cactuar) states you can find Cactuars easily in the *Longwythe Rest Area*, which is Southwest of *Hammerhead*.

> **How and Where to find Cactuars**
>
> First, you can find Cactuars pretty easily in the area north of the Longwythe Rest Area -- which is just southwest of Hammerhead.
>
> However, you will need the **Beast Whistle** to call enemies to you, which you get in Chapter 4. They can spawn without it, but it is very rare and much easier to just blow the whistle until it comes out.